# Preventing twitter bootstrap carousel from auto sliding on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So is there anyway to prevent twitter bootstrap carousel from auto sliding on the page load unless the next or previous button is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Or if you're using Bootstrap 3.0 you can stop the cycling with data-interval="false" for instance

`<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">`

Other helpful carousel data attributes are here -> http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage

Comment: This is not 100% the answer to the question because it also stops it from cycling even when a button is clicked. But it was exactly what I was looking for. So thank you anyway!

Comment: `data-interval="false"` also works with **Bootstrap 4**

Answer (score 53):

Actually, the problem is now solved. I added the 'pause' argument to the method 'carousel' like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

Anyway, thanks so much @Yohn for your tips toward this solution.

Comment: This will start sliding after prev/next, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18208327/463065 if that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: for a more specific one would be  `$(function(){  $("#idName").carousel('pause'); });`

Answer (score 43):

The problem with carousel automatically sliding after prev/next button press is solved.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
});
```

[GitHub commit 78b927b](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2521)

Answer (score 17):

if you're using **bootstrap 3** set `data-interval="false"` on the HTML structure of carousel

example:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
```

Answer (score 11):

- Use `data-interval="false"` to stop automatic slide
- Use `data-wrap="false"` to stop circular slide

Answer (score 10):

add this to your coursel div :

```
data-interval="false"
```

Comment: Michael Kopec's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18817670/369450) from 2 years ago already says to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Below are the list of parameters for bootstrap carousel.
Like Interval, pause, wrap:

[image]

For more details refer this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Hope this will help you :)

**Note:** This is for further help. I mean how you can customise or change default behaviour once carousel is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you should go to check the official instruction about carousel, for me, i have not found answer above, because of multiple versions of bootstrap, I'm using b4-alpha and **i want the autoplay effect stop.**

```
$(document).ready({
    pause:true,
    interval:false
});
```

this script does not make any effect while mouse leave that page, exactly carousel area. go to official definition and find those :

[image]

So you will find why.if carousel page onmouseover event triggered, page will pause, while mouse out of that page, it'll resume again.

**So, if you want a page stop forever and rotate manually**, you can just set `data-interval='false'`.

Answer (score 1):

--Use data-interval="false" to stop automatic slide
--Use data-wrap="false" to stop circular slide

...

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 4 simply remove the 'data-ride="carousel"' from the carousel div. This removes auto play at load time.

To enable the auto play again you would still have to use the "play" call in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5.2, just remove `data-bs-ride`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#disable-touch-swiping

Take note that `data-bs-interval="false"` from Bootstrap 5.0 has been deprecated on Bootstrap 5.2

---

Bootstrap 5.0, add `data-bs-interval="false"`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#disable-touch-swiping