# How do I on page load stop two carousels from auto scrolling?

Tags: javascript, carousel, owl-carousel

I just want to say a big thank you for helping this newbie out!
I am using this '[Owl Carousel](http://nicesnippets.com/live/best-product-display-slider-using-bootstrap-demo.html)' product slider twice in my website but I can't seem to create a 'on page load stop auto advance'. I can't edit the remote JS file which I think is causing me problems. The latest version of the carousel is [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html). I know this question is very similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358499/preventing-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-from-auto-sliding-on-page-load) using this `$(document).ready(function() {$('.carousel').carousel('pause');});` but where do I put it as its a remote file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the Owl Carousel API and pass the autoPlay option with the value false as the documentation states.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all third party *things* like this come with some way to configure them. There usually is also an API that allows you to control the functionality. The source of these types of answers are usually with the documentation of the *thing*.

In this case, there is an example that shows you how to use the autoplay configuration here:

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! I checked the default values were all set to auto-play false. Had another pair of eyes cast over my code and I had this piece of code in my html (data-ride="carousel") that made the auto play true!! Wasn't the JS after all!

Comment: Glad you sorted it!