# Carousel - stop the side scrolling

Tags: javascript, carousel

Sorry for the silly question.
I was searching for a carousel with a button.
I found this template on Bootply that did exactly what I wanted to do.
I'm quite new at developing.

Maybe someone can explain to me how can I get rid of the side scrolling effect.
I know that I have to add something to the JavaScript part but I don't know what.

I just want the users to be able to control the slide scrolling by clicking on the buttons on the bottom.

Here's the link of the template : [Carousel with buttons](https://www.bootply.com/113737)

Thank you in advance

S.Ach

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `slide` class from `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">` will remove the animation.

Comment: Thank you @gempir , easy as pie !

Comment: @S.Ach make sure to mark the Answer correct so others don't need to put more answers :)

Comment: Actually I tried but I'm missing something, the effect still working

Comment: I replaced <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> by <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel"> and it didn't work then I just removed the javaScript  line and it worked (and yes I pressed run ^^)

Comment: Just removing "slide" and pressing run removes the animation like you wanted

Comment: I think I misunderstood. You want to auto slide gone? So the slider only moves manually.

Comment: I want users use only the buttons on the bottom to scroll between the slides. English is not my mother tongue sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

I realized for your question you want to remove auto change the slide after clicked on button by user

```
    $("button").click(function(){
               $(".carousel").removeClass("slide");
     })
```

I found same question in this link.
[Preventing twitter bootstrap carousel from auto sliding on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358499/preventing-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-from-auto-sliding-on-page-load)

Comment: Hello @mohamed Karimi, It seems working that way thank you

Comment: Goodluck friend.